# Why does R ellipsis (...) match more arguments when using nested functions?

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

I would like to understand why the `...` argument matches the `extra` argument when nesting `f()` within `g()`.

Say that `f()` is this function:

```r
f <- function(..., extra = NULL) {
    . <- list(...)
    print(.)
}
```

The output is, as expected, what is contained in the `...` argument:

```r
f("a", "b", "c", extra = "123")

# [[1]]
# [1] "a"

# [[2]]
# [1] "b"

# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
```

However, when using it within another function, say `g()`:

```r
g <- function(..., extra = NULL) {
    f(..., extra)
}
```

The `...` also captures the `extra` argument:

```r
g("a", "b", "c", extra = "123")

# [[1]]
# [1] "a"

# [[2]]
# [1] "b"

# [[3]]
# [1] "c"

# [[4]]
# [1] "123"
```

My question is twofold: (1) why is this the case and (2) how to correctly handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `f()` you define and set an argument called extra, that is never used, thus it doesnt appear anywhere. The `f(..., extra)` in `g()` captures all the arguments in g and assigns them to `...` in `f()`. The extra in `g(..., extra)` has nothing to do with the extra in `f(..., extra = NULL)`. They have the same names but live in different environments - the environments of `g()`and `f()` respectively. To achieve the same behaviour assign the `g()`'s extra to `f()`'s extra in the function call:

```
g1 <- function(..., extra = NULL) {
    f(..., extra = extra)
}
> g1("a", "b", "c", extra = NULL)
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c"

>
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thanks!